# Unable to parse Double quote from api in ios

Tags: ios, swift, encoding, double-quotes

Receiving data from the api as *"Enjoy FREE 6” x 6” Simple Book (20 pages)"*

and the same is being displayed as "Enjoy FREE **6â x 6â** Simple Book (20 pages)"

Unable to escape Double quote from the api, any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Most probably an encoding problem. How exactly do you get the data, and how do you convert the data to a string?

Comment: Getting this data from json file uploaded on AWS. below is the code

`Alamofire.request(url, method: method, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseString { (response) in
            completionHandler(response,true)
        }`

Comment: The double quote after `6` in your post is U+201D RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK which has encoded in UTF-8 as 0xE2 0x80 0x9D. If some part of your code mis-decodes it in ISO-8859-1 (ISO-LATIN-1), it is displayed as `â` as 0xE2 represents `â` in ISO-8859-1, and other two bytes are unprintable characters. This may happen with various reasons, but I guess replacing `.responseString` with `.responseString(encoding: .utf8)` can be a good first try.

Comment: Did it, no luck so far

Answer (score 0):

If you do not find a better solution

```
let newString = oldString.replacingOccurrences(of: "â", with: "\"")
```